# Post data on check/uncheck

Tags: jquery

I use AJAX to post data when a checkbox is checked/unchecked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(":input,:hidden").serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mpt_planningen_overzicht.update.php",
      data: formData,
      success: function(result) { /* GET THE TO BE RETURNED DATA */
        $("#resultaat").html(result); /* THE RETURNED DATA WILL BE SHOWN IN    THIS DIV */               
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="resultaat">
  <form name="planning">
    <input name="dkw" type="checkbox" value="1">
  </form>
</div>
```

However when I select a checkbox, nothing happens.

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing happens'? Have you checked the console to see if there's any errors? Or if the request is even sent? I can also see that you have a couple of issues - you're calling `preventDefault()` on the global `event` object, which may not exist in all browsers, you should use the `change` event for checkboxes, and you're calling `serialize()` on the inputs when it needs to be called on the `form`.

Comment: Console error may occurs for this line `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Remove `event.preventDefault();` and it will work.